# Call class.method in new thread that requires a parameter

Tags: java, multithreading

Okay so right now I have essentially this code:

```
class a {

public void ab() {
    b thread = new b();
     thread.bb(this);
    }
}

class b {

    public void bb(a _a) {
     //execute code here in new thread so ab can continue running
    }
}
```

However this doesn't open it in a new thread, and yes I did research this, all the solutions I found didn't leave any option to send a parameter (this) to the bb method

How to call class.method in new thread that requires a parameter?

Comment: you did research on what ?,  go through this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a thread, you must have an instance of `java.lang.Thread`, of which `b` is not.  You can extend thread to achieve this.

```
class b extends Thread {
```

A Thread runs asynchronously whatever you place in its `run()` method, which you can override from its original (empty) implementation.

```
class b extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't allow you to pass an instance of `a`.  Your best option here is to take an instance of `a` as an instance variable in the constructor of `b`.

```
class b extends Thread {

    private final a _a;

    public b(a _a) {
        this._a = _a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //now you can use _a here
    }
}
```

Finally, to run the thread asynchronously, you don't call the newly implemented `run()` method, but you call `Thread#start()`, which invokes the `run()` method in a new thread.

```
class a {

    public void ab() {
        b thread = new b(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

As a side note, standard Java convention is to start class names with capital letters, so you should rename `a` to `A` and so forth.  This however won't make any difference as far as compilation or execution goes.

Comment: Okay, my first problem with this is that I have tried all of that, when I do that thread.start() is just an error saying start doesn't exist. The second problem is doesn't this create a NEW instance of a? I need the specific instance that is already being ran as it is the gui

Comment: You need to extend Thread in `class b` in order for `start` to exist.  This *does not* create a new instance of `a`, because the enclosing `this` is passed as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but forget java, its a joke of a language.

Answer (score 2):

The question is "How to call class.method in new thread that requires a parameter?"

The answer is "You can't"... but, it's a workaround: use an instance with a constructor to define a "context" of execution.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
   MyThread( A a ){
      this.a = a;
   }
   @Override public void run() {
      ... use this.a; // a was the "parameter"
   }
   private A a;
}

MyThread myThread = new MyThread( aValue );
myThread.start();
```

Comment: I have splitted the line to be more explicit: constructor call